# How to disable auto-save in emacs only for files opened as root

Tags: tramp, auto-save, sudo, root

I want to use emacs auto-save feature with tramp, but only for file that I don't open using sudo. My current configuration, based on the [tramp documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/Auto_002dsave-and-Backup.html), looks like this:

```
;;;;;;;; BAKUCP ;;;;;;;;
;; Backup remote files locally to stop autosave pain
(setq tramp-backup-directory "~/.emacs-backup")
(unless (file-directory-p tramp-backup-directory)
  (make-directory tramp-backup-directory))
(if (file-accessible-directory-p tramp-backup-directory)
    (setq tramp-auto-save-directory tramp-backup-directory)
  (error "Cannot write to ~/.emacs-backup"))
;; Don't backup su and sudo files
(setq backup-enable-predicate
      (lambda (name)
        (and (normal-backup-enable-predicate name)
             (not
              (let ((method (file-remote-p name 'method)))
                (when (stringp method)
                  (member method '("su" "sudo"))))))))
```

It is forbidding creating remote backups of files edited as superuser but auto-saved files are still created on my local machine. Is there any way to disable that without disabling auto-save at all?

Answer (score 2):

Backup and auto-save are different operations, controlled by different variables.

If you want to discard auto-save for files opened as root, you might change the buffer-local variable `auto-save-file-name-transforms`. Something like this (untested):

```
(add-hook
 'find-file-hook
 (lambda ()
   (when (and (stringp buffer-file-name)
          (string-equal (file-remote-p buffer-file-name 'user) "root"))
     (setq buffer-auto-save-file-name nil))))
```

Comment: If you put this in the users' `.emacs` file, it will not be read if emacs is opened with `sudo` though correct? So when would this code be in effect?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Everything in ~/.emacs is evaluated at start of Emacs, unless you start Emacs with the -Q or similar option.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that opening `emacs` with `sudo emacs` would not read the config file in the users' home directory.  I realize now this is probably a good answer for when something is opened as sudo from an instance of emacs opened as a user.

Comment: What variable would check if the file were opened as root? (i.e. opened with the `/sudo::/` tramp method)?

Comment: `default-directory` is a buffer-local variable, which tells you the current directory of that buffer. `(file-remote-p default-directory)` returns non-nil, when you are remote. `(file-remote-p default-directory 'user)` gives you the remote user name, `"root"` for example.